# unkown command '<' when using sed command

Tags: bash

I'm trying to update xml file via bash script.

I saw some answers which advise to use `sed` command.
I'm trying to do so, but getting errors, and can't find the right way.
I have the following xml file:

```
<System>
   <HW value="true" />
   <Tm4 value="true" />
</System>
```

I want to replace the value of `HW` from `true` to `false`:

`<HW value="true" />`   →   `<HW value="false" />`

I wrote the following script:

```
sed -i '<HW value="false" \/>' / <HW value="true" \/> myXmlFile.xml
```

But getting the following error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token '<'
```

What am I doing wrong and what is the right code line?

Comment: The first character (`<`) of the string passed as the argument is the command.  `sed` has no command `<`.  Perhaps you want to use the `s` command: `sed -e 's@pattern@repl@'`

Comment: The syntax is not correct. Try this instead: `sed -i 's/<HW value="true" \/>/<HW value="false" \/>/g' myXmlFile.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better choose other character than / to edit XML with sed, to make your code readable, eg.

```
sed -i 's|<HW value="false" />|<HW value="true" />|g' myXmlFile.xml
```